# Boxplotting Masked Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, boxplot

How can i boxplot only the non-masked values of a MaskedArray ? I tought this would happen automatically by `boxplot(ma)` but this seems to boxplot the non-masked array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are right -- `plt.boxplot` ignores the mask if sent a masked array.
So it looks like you'll have to give `boxplot` some extra help by sending it only the values which are not masked. Since each row of the array may have a different number of unmasked values, you won't be able to use a numpy array. You'll have to form a Python sequence of vectors:

```
z = [[y for y in row if y] for row in x.T]
```

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()

N=20
M=10

x = np.random.random((M,N))
mask=np.random.random_integers(0,1,N*M).reshape((M,N))
x = np.ma.array(x,mask=mask)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.boxplot(x)

z = [[y for y in row if y] for row in x.T]
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.boxplot(z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Above, the first subplot shows a boxplot of all the data in `x` (ignoring the mask), and the second subplot shows a boxplot of only those values which are not masked.

Comment: mm, what if i do not mask colums in an array but e.g. `ma.masked_equal(0)`, which makes the suggested manner a bit more complicated ...

Comment: @rubae: So not all rows have the same number of values?

Comment: i'm having 6 `np.ma`'s of (N,M)-size, so i want to have 6 doxplot of these arrays, in which all values equal to zero are masked by `np.nan` and whih are randomly all over the place in the arrays ... (and which i don't want in my boxplot)