# Boxplotting multiple masked arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, boxplot

I am trying to boxplot several arrays that have masked all of the -9999 values (equipment malfunction values) in my dataset. It seems that np.boxplot ignores the mask of the values and plots them anyway. How can I get numpy to exclude the masked values in each data set?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.ma.array([229.5,374.0,536.5,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,-9999,182.0,42.5,49.0])
b = np.ma.array([363.0,118.5,159.0,-9999,311.0,516.0,380.0,338.5,223.0,211.5,128.5])
c = np.ma.array([205.5,277.5,141.5,278.0,302.0,251.0,299.0,250.0,315.5,92.1,211.9])

a = np.ma.masked_less( a, -9000 )
b = np.ma.masked_less( b, -9000 )
c = np.ma.masked_less( c, -9000 )

data_to_plot = [ a , b, c ]
labels = [ 'a', 'c', 'c' ]

fig = plt.figure( 3, figsize = ( 8, 10 ) )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 111, frameon = False )
bp = ax.boxplot( data_to_plot, patch_artist = True, widths = .85, 
                labels = labels, vert = True)
plt.setp( bp[ 'boxes' ], color = 'black', alpha = .8, linewidth = 3 )
plt.setp( bp[ 'whiskers' ], color = 'black', linewidth = 3 )
plt.setp( bp[ 'fliers' ], markeredgecolor = 'black', alpha = 1, markersize = 30, marker = '.' )
plt.setp( bp[ 'medians' ], color = 'orange', linewidth = 3 )
plt.setp( bp[ 'means' ], color = 'black' )
plt.setp( bp[ 'caps' ], color = 'black', linewidth = 4 )

colors = ['r', 'b', 'g', ]
for b in ( bp ):
    for patch, color in zip( bp[ 'boxes' ], colors ):
        patch.set_facecolor( color )
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot of masked -9999 data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code produces errors so it's hard to tell if that is the code you are using. I'm not sure how matplotlib treats masked array because I would generally create a new array with only the data I need. You can replace:

```
 a = np.ma.masked_less( a, -9000 )
 b = np.ma.masked_less( b, -9000 )
 c = np.ma.masked_less( c, -9000 )
```

with

```
 a = a[a>-9000]
 b = b[b>-9000]
 c = c[c>-9000]
```

Comment: Meanwhile [this shows](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Plotting_values_with_masked_arrays.html) matplotlib ignores masked values.

Comment: @Parfait, you are the hero Gotham needs. That link shows a limitation of matplotlib well. The answer still addresses the how, but the comment addresses the why.

Comment: @Parfait I read through that before posting but unsure what exactly it's showing (I'm sort of a rookie when it comes to coding). Is it showing that it just shifts the range of values it looks at to exclude the masked values? 

Edit: Also, the code is pretty similar but I changed how I call in the data because it's a large dataframe (834 x 166) so errors coming from there I'm guessing.

Comment: After putting in the new code, the array changed from: [229.5,374.0,536.5,-9999.0,-9999.0,-9999.0,-9999.0,-9999.0,182.0,103.5,68.0,43.0,42.5,49.0] 
to 
[229.5,374.0,536.5,93.5,89.5,98.0,86.0,102.0,124.0,52.0,62.0,79.5,78.5,74.0].
Should replacing the ma.masked_less with the inequality statement have replaced the -9999 values like that and changed these data so?

Comment: @danrod13 ... only difference I see is link uses the `np.ma.masked_where` but `np.ma.masked_less` is a convenience wrapper for this method per [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_less.html). From your code, I do not know why plotting does not mask your intended range. Possibly it has something to do with negative values. I would post this as a possible bug in a [Git issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) for matplotlib team. Be sure to include a reproducible example like you do here.

Comment: @Parfait saw that same thing. Also found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029912/boxplotting-masked-arrays but I'm not python savvy enough to apply it. I figure I'd have to do it as I dealt with each variable but when I did that I got an error that said it couldn't iterate float32's.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13533

Work around solution to matplotlib.boxplots not recognizing masked values.